# How to autofocus a element periodically - React

Tags: reactjs

I need help with my recat application. 
I have a button that selects itself once the application starts (with autofocus), so that you can control the function associated with it via the keyboard. 
The problem is that as soon as I select another element on the page, the button is obviously no longer selected and I can no longer call the function from the keyboard.
So I would like to understand if it is possible to set a timer so that the button selects itself every x seconds.
I attach the component code.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Spot extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    iframeSrcs: ["/300x250", "/160x600", "/468x60"],
    heightSrcs: [250, 600, 60],
    widthSrcs: [300, 160, 468],
    visibility: false
  };

  reload = () => {
    const iframeLength = this.state.iframeSrcs.length;
    if (this.state.index < iframeLength) {
      this.setState({
        index: this.state.index + 1,
        visibility: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ index: 0, visibility: true }); //starting again
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ visibility: false });
    }, 15000);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 500,
            opacity: 0
          }}
          onClick={this.reload}
          autoFocus="true"
          onKeyDown={this.reload}
        >
          pubblicità
        </button>
        {this.state.visibility ? (
          <iframe
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              left: 100,
              right: 0,
              top: 10
            }}
            key={this.state.index}
            title="AdSlot"
            src={this.state.iframeSrcs[this.state.index]}
            height={this.state.heightSrcs[this.state.index]}
            width={this.state.widthSrcs[this.state.index]}
            scrolling="no"
            frameborder="0"
            allowFullScreen="true"
          />
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Slot;
```

Thanks to those who want to help me.
P.S. I know that many parts of my code are not the best, but I'm approaching react right now, so it's the best I managed to do

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an interval function, that focueses your button periodically.
Thisfunction will get called every 5 seconds:

```
setInterval(() => {
  // Your select logic
}, 5000);
```

For more information check: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementById("your button id").focus();
}, your delay);
```

This is not react specific, but vanilla JS. I don't know if it'll work, but it's the best I could think of right now. You could give it a try, and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

> so that you can control the function associated with it via the keyboard

I suppose that you actually want to call the action when pressing `Enter` on the keyboard right?

If so, then it is recommended to add an event listener to the window/document in order to call that action whenever you press the enter button:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Spot extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    iframeSrcs: ["/300x250", "/160x600", "/468x60"],
    heightSrcs: [250, 600, 60],
    widthSrcs: [300, 160, 468],
    visibility: false
  };

  componentDidMount()
  {
      document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount()
  {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown.bind(this));
  }

  onKeyDown(event)
  {
      // 13 is the code for the Enter key
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          this.reload();
      }
  }    

  reload()
  {
    const iframeLength = this.state.iframeSrcs.length;
    if (this.state.index < iframeLength) {
      this.setState({
        index: this.state.index + 1,
        visibility: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ index: 0, visibility: true }); //starting again
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ visibility: false });
    }, 15000);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 500,
            opacity: 0
          }}
          onClick={this.reload}
        >
          pubblicità
        </button>
        {this.state.visibility ? (
          <iframe
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              left: 100,
              right: 0,
              top: 10
            }}
            key={this.state.index}
            title="AdSlot"
            src={this.state.iframeSrcs[this.state.index]}
            height={this.state.heightSrcs[this.state.index]}
            width={this.state.widthSrcs[this.state.index]}
            scrolling="no"
            frameborder="0"
            allowFullScreen="true"
          />
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Slot;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer first of all.
I tried to use your code but it gives me this error:
"TypeError: this.reload is not a function"

Comment: I just updated my answer. you must bind the current context when adding/removing the event listener: `this.onKeyDown.bind(this)`

Comment: ok, now it works but it is not exactly what I was looking for. In this configuration I need to click on a part of the empty page, to make the button self-select. Instead, what I would like is an automatic self-selection every second.
I have probably not been clear in describing the problem, I hope I have been clearer now.